# How can I create input field/form in excel?

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I need to create input form in excel, but the ones I found are quiet different from what I need.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxLNQnK5luweby1KYXRqR2c5ZjA/edit?usp=sharing

Here, you can see the type of form I need to create. Its an excel file with such form, but the macros are password protected, so I cannot see nothing more than the ready form.
Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

that's not a form, that file just uses some cells as a form. if you are googling forms for vba you will not find your answer.

if you need to add controls to your fomr you need to enable developer ribbon.
go to file>options>custumize ribbon then check Developer, now you can add butons like the save one to your excel sheet.

then rigth click that button and assign the macro that will do the job.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply bto.rdz.

Comment: I have the developer tab enabled, but I needed to see how the macro is done or any tips about it. This was the part what I didnt understand`.
Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to view the macro you can right click on the worksheet and select view code, if the vba is protected there is software that will retrieve the password if you have forgotten it